# How do I rprint an array holding data that corresponds to user inputted data?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, object, for-loop

I am trying to display the array corresponding to the user's request *in this case it would be to display all car arrays that have the corresponding make and have it printed. (there are 11 car arrays, all named car1, car2 etc..

Here's my block of code:

```
var car1 = new Car("Toyota", "Camry", "Gold", "2006", "RT14-W32", true);
var car2 = new Car("Hyundai", "Elantra", "Silver", "2012", "CRTW-34S", (false);
var car3 = new Car("Honda", "Civic", "Grey", "2010", "SASY-232", false);
var car4 = new Car("Toyota", "Corolla", "Blue", "2009", "BARF-343", (true);
var car5 = new Car("Tesla", "Model S", "Black", "2019", "COOL-CAR", true);
var car6 = new Car("Mercedes", "B-Class", "Black", "2018", "RICH-999", true);
var car7 = new Car("Toyota", "Rav4","Red", "2014", "DART-565", false);
var car8 = new Car("Hyundai", "SantaFe", "Silver", "2016", "WDYO-227", false);
var car9 = new Car("Hyundai", "Accent", "White", "2014", "QRT-411", true);
var car10 = new Car("Honda", "Accord","Red", "2017", "VTTY-233", false);

console.log(car4);


    function filterByMake()
    { 
        var inputFilter = document.getElementById("tbFilter").value;

        for( x = 0; x < 11; x++)
    {       
            if (car[x].inputFilter == car[x].make)
            {
            document.getElementById("Output").innerHTML += car[x].year + " " + car[x].color + " " + car[x].make + " " + car[x].model +" " + " " + car[x].license + "<br/> Car available for sale? " + car[x].forSale;
            }
    }

}
```

The console says that car is not defined, should i be concatenating the counter and the array instead? unsure how that would work in an if statement,

thoughts?
Any tips or corrections are appreciated

Comment: What is your `Car` constructor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you meant `window['car' + x]` which is crazy!

You should create an array of objects as follow:

```
var cars = [new Car("Toyota", "Camry", "Gold", "2006", "RT14-W32", true),
  new Car("Hyundai", "Elantra", "Silver", "2012", "CRTW-34S", (false),
  new Car("Honda", "Civic", "Grey", "2010", "SASY-232", false),
  new Car("Toyota", "Corolla", "Blue", "2009", "BARF-343", (true),
  new Car("Tesla", "Model S", "Black", "2019", "COOL-CAR", true),
  new Car("Mercedes", "B-Class", "Black", "2018", "RICH-999", true),
  new Car("Toyota", "Rav4", "Red", "2014", "DART-565", false),
  new Car("Hyundai", "SantaFe", "Silver", "2016", "WDYO-227", false),
  new Car("Hyundai", "Accent", "White", "2014", "QRT-411", true),
  new Car("Honda", "Accord", "Red", "2017", "VTTY-233", false)
];

console.log(car4);

function filterByMake() {
  var inputFilter = document.getElementById("tbFilter").value;

  for (x = 0; x < cars.length; x++) {
  if (inputFilter === cars[x].make) {
    document.getElementById("Output").innerHTML += cars[x].year + " " + cars[x].color + " " + cars[x].make + " " + cars[x].model + " " + " " + cars[x].license + "<br/> Car available for sale? " + cars[x].forSale;
  }
}
```

Your approach is finding a car, so you can use the function `find`

```
var cars = [new Car("Toyota", "Camry", "Gold", "2006", "RT14-W32", true),
    new Car("Hyundai", "Elantra", "Silver", "2012", "CRTW-34S", (false),
    new Car("Honda", "Civic", "Grey", "2010", "SASY-232", false),
    new Car("Toyota", "Corolla", "Blue", "2009", "BARF-343", (true),
    new Car("Tesla", "Model S", "Black", "2019", "COOL-CAR", true),
    new Car("Mercedes", "B-Class", "Black", "2018", "RICH-999", true),
    new Car("Toyota", "Rav4", "Red", "2014", "DART-565", false),
    new Car("Hyundai", "SantaFe", "Silver", "2016", "WDYO-227", false),
    new Car("Hyundai", "Accent", "White", "2014", "QRT-411", true),
    new Car("Honda", "Accord", "Red", "2017", "VTTY-233", false)
];

console.log(car4);

function filterByMake() {
  var inputFilter = document.getElementById("tbFilter").value;
  var found cars.find(function(c) {
    return inputFilter === c.make;
  });
  if (found) {
      document.getElementById("Output").innerHTML += cars[x].year + " " + cars[x].color + " " + cars[x].make + " " + cars[x].model + " " + " " + cars[x].license + "<br/> Car available for sale? " + cars[x].forSale;
  }
}
```